Differences between Revelation 22:21 in translations
In many English translations of the Bible, the classic reading of revelation 22:21 is

The grace of our Lord Jesus Christ be with you all. Amen. -KJV

But many omit the Amen. My question is what is the manuscript evidence for this omission?

This is simply a difference in textual references, not translations.

You should consult UBS5 and NA28 for the manuscripts which support various readings.

I find it particularly edifying to research such questions. It has to be said that the question of the differences between Revelation 22:21 in various biblical translations is essential to understanding the impact of translation choices on the biblical message. Here's a proposal for a detailed answer, based on biblical and textual analysis.
Basic text: Revelation 22:21
Greek text (TR/NA28):
"Ἡ χάρις τοῦ Κυρίου Ἰησοῦ Χριστοῦ μετὰ πάντων. Ἀμήν."
Main translations
Louis Segond 1910:
"May the grace of the Lord Jesus be with all! Amen!"
Emphasizes a general declaration of grace for all believers.
Darby Version:
"The grace of our Lord Jesus Christ be with all the saints. Amen."
Adds nuance by potentially limiting grace to the saints (faithful believers).
King James Version (KJV):
"The grace of our Lord Jesus Christ be with you all. Amen."
Universal, similar to Louis Segond.
Osty New Testament:
"The grace of the Lord Jesus be with you all."
Omits "Amen," simplifying the text.
Jerusalem Bible:
"May the grace of the Lord Jesus be with you all. Amen."
Specifies "you", introducing a more direct address.
Main differences
Universal or limited reference
Some translations (Darby, Osty) add a notion of restriction ("saints"), which can be seen as a theological interpretation linked to sanctification.
General translations (Louis Segond, KJV) are inclusive and reflect a grace offered to all mankind.
Presence of "Amen
Some versions include "Amen" (Segond, KJV), marking a liturgical or solemn ending.
Others (Osty, some critical editions) omit it, indicating that the word may be a late addition.
Lexical and theological choices
"Grace" (χάρις) can be interpreted as a gift of salvation or as an ongoing spiritual blessing.
Theological interpretations
The nature of grace
The grace mentioned here is that offered by Jesus Christ to all believers. The universal versions recall the free access to salvation for all (John 3:16). The restrictive versions emphasize that only the saints benefit fully from this grace (Hebrews 12:14).
Inclusion or exclusion
The Darby version refers to a possible exclusion, which raises a debate about conditional versus unconditional grace. However, Paul reminds us in Ephesians 2:8-9 that grace is an unmerited gift, received by faith.
Text authority
Original Greek manuscripts vary slightly. Some older manuscripts omit "Amen", but its inclusion in the majority of translations reflects a liturgical tradition.
Textual and contextual evidence
Early manuscripts
Byzantine manuscripts generally include "Amen".
Codex Sinaiticus and Vaticanus do not, indicating that the phrase may have been added by scribes.
Eschatological context
Revelation 22:21 concludes a universal revelation: grace must therefore be understood as a message from God to all mankind.
Biblical harmony
The grace offered here aligns with Paul's words in 2 Corinthians 13:13, where a similar blessing concludes his epistle.
Conclusion and remark: The differences in Revelation 22:21 illustrate the importance of translation choices. However, they all converge on a central message: the grace of Jesus Christ is essential to the Christian life. It is both a universal invitation and a special blessing for those who believe and live in sanctification.
God bless you all!

Roger Omanson's "A Textual Guide to the Greek New Testament" says this on page 552, on Revelation 22:21 with reference to Ἀμήν:
22.21 omit ἀμὴν.  {B}

The Textus Receptus, in agreement with a few uncials and almost all minuscules and many ancient versions, concludes the book with ἀμὴν.  If, however, this word were present originally, it is difficult to account for its omission in those manuscripts that do not have it.  Some modern translations include the word "Amen" (RSV, NRSV, NIV, NJB), while others do not (REB, TEV, TOB, FC, Seg).

Note: ἀμὴν was bolded by me in Omanson's textual guide for clarity.
